# How to authenticate to an API using an external identity provider?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

### I have the following setup on the same machine:

- WSO2-AM
- WSO2-IM-KM (Identity manager as key manager)

The identity manager federates authentication to an external OpenID identity provider.

### What I've done so far:

- Share the databases between the two components
- Make WSO2-AM delegate the authentication to WSO2-IM-KM
- Configure the external provider to the generated service provider (generated in WSO2-IM-KM when creating an application in WSO2-AM store)

### The current behavior:

- I can obtain an authorization code by calling the following URL : https://my.site:9444/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=pkYcC4xFQ1jt6dQbdZAe6savv4oa&scope=phone+email+address+openid+profile&redirect_uri=https://my.site:9443/store/jagg/jaggery_oidc_acs.jag&nonce=3734e7d4c22f1&state=128d20e14c884, the authentication succeeds, then the `jaggery_oidc_acs.jag` endpoint fails
- Since the `jaggery_oidc_acs.jag` endpoint fails, I manually retrieve the `code` then `POST` it to https://my.site:8243/token which returns me an `access_token`, a `refresh_token`, and an `id_token`

### My problems :

- How am I supposed to automate the manual step I described before? Am I in charge of creating a dedicated endpoint to do it, in order to keep the `authorization_code` obfuscated from the client, or is there a built-in endpoint in WSO2? If appropriate, what is this endpoint?
- Is there an endpoint that generates the `oauth2/authorize` URL?

### After further research:

I have found the following document https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Authorization+Code+Grant that seems to indicate that I need a "client", but I don't have one, I just need my API to be authenticated with the external identity provider.

Comment: do u have any error logs in the API manager server during this error? I think there should some error on the logs (say authorization related error, etc)

Comment: are you saying that jaggery_oidc_acs.jag should work?

Comment: yes. see https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+OpenID+Connect which uses  jaggery_oidc_acs.jag

Answer (score 0):

Answering to problem 01

If you want to use authorization code grant type to get access token definitely there should be a callback URL to get authorization code. If your callback URL is real no need to do any manual step, simply just retrieve authorization code from request query parameters sent to callback URL. You can check this behavior from playground2 sample application [1] where callback URL is http://localhost:8080/playground2/oauth2client.

Answering to problem 02

Please check OAuth2AuthzEPUrl tag in identity.xml

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Setting+Up+the+Sample+Webapp